# Parsing json in android with nameless array interested in only one kind of object

Tags: android, json

How do I parse this `json` as of now I am only interested in user object but later I may need to parse other object so future change should be easy

```
[ { "url": "https://api.github.com/gists/10232136", "forks_url": "https://api.github.com/gists/10232136/forks", "commits_url": "https://api.github.com/gists/10232136/commits", "id": "10232136", "git_pull_url": "https://gist.github.com/10232136.git", "git_push_url": "https://gist.github.com/10232136.git", "html_url": "https://gist.github.com/10232136", "files": { "gulpfile-viget-pattern.js": { "filename": "gulpfile-viget-pattern.js", "type": "application/javascript", "language": "JavaScript", "raw_url": "https://gist.githubusercontent.com/andrewmartin/10232136/raw/72c67881fe717ecf35dd2a0f4524fca989b9b643/gulpfile-viget-pattern.js", "size": 426 } }, "public": true, "created_at": "2014-04-09T06:34:16Z", "updated_at": "2014-04-09T06:34:16Z", "description": "gulpfile-viget-pattern-test.js", "comments": 0, "user": { "login": "andrewmartin", "id": 273842, "avatar_url": "https://avatars.githubusercontent.com/u/273842?", "gravatar_id": "3377b3e694bdacac127ca9ee6c871c52", "url": "https://api.github.com/users/andrewmartin", "html_url": "https://github.com/andrewmartin", "followers_url": "https://api.github.com/users/andrewmartin/followers", "following_url": "https://api.github.com/users/andrewmartin/following{/other_user}", "gists_url": "https://api.github.com/users/andrewmartin/gists{/gist_id}", "starred_url": "https://api.github.com/users/andrewmartin/starred{/owner}{/repo}", "subscriptions_url": "https://api.github.com/users/andrewmartin/subscriptions", "organizations_url": "https://api.github.com/users/andrewmartin/orgs", "repos_url": "https://api.github.com/users/andrewmartin/repos", "events_url": "https://api.github.com/users/andrewmartin/events{/privacy}", "received_events_url": "https://api.github.com/users/andrewmartin/received_events", "type": "User", "site_admin": false }, "comments_url": "https://api.github.com/gists/10232136/comments" }, { "url": "https://api.github.com/gists/10232076", "forks_url": "https://api.github.com/gists/10232076/forks", "commits_url": "https://api.github.com/gists/10232076/commits", "id": "10232076", "git_pull_url": "https://gist.github.com/10232076.git", "git_push_url": "https://gist.github.com/10232076.git", "html_url": "https://gist.github.com/10232076", "files": { "ScrollableGridView.java": { "filename": "ScrollableGridView.java", "type": "text/plain", "language": "Java", "raw_url": "https://gist.githubusercontent.com/kumarvmsathish/10232076/raw/490b09b86dc7d154d12dd754a1cb0ac47276343c/ScrollableGridView.java", "size": 1399 } }, "public": true, "created_at": "2014-04-09T06:33:20Z", "updated_at": "2014-04-09T06:33:20Z", "description": null, "comments": 0, "user": { "login": "kumarvmsathish", "id": 5295401, "avatar_url": "https://avatars.githubusercontent.com/u/5295401?", "gravatar_id": "d85ebb855467b4c0aa03d4b394a3396f", "url": "https://api.github.com/users/kumarvmsathish", "html_url": "https://github.com/kumarvmsathish", "followers_url": "https://api.github.com/users/kumarvmsathish/followers", "following_url": "https://api.github.com/users/kumarvmsathish/following{/other_user}", "gists_url": "https://api.github.com/users/kumarvmsathish/gists{/gist_id}", "starred_url": "https://api.github.com/users/kumarvmsathish/starred{/owner}{/repo}", "subscriptions_url": "https://api.github.com/users/kumarvmsathish/subscriptions", "organizations_url": "https://api.github.com/users/kumarvmsathish/orgs", "repos_url": "https://api.github.com/users/kumarvmsathish/repos", "events_url": "https://api.github.com/users/kumarvmsathish/events{/privacy}", "received_events_url": "https://api.github.com/users/kumarvmsathish/received_events", "type": "User", "site_admin": false }, "comments_url": "https://api.github.com/gists/10232076/comments" }, { "url": "https://api.github.com/gists/10232038", "forks_url": "https://api.github.com/gists/10232038/forks", "commits_url": "https://api.github.com/gists/10232038/commits", "id": "10232038", "git_pull_url": "https://gist.github.com/10232038.git", "git_push_url": "https://gist.github.com/10232038.git", "html_url": "https://gist.github.com/10232038", "files": { "osx_oracle_client.md": { "filename": "osx_oracle_client.md", "type": "text/plain", "language": "Markdown", "raw_url": "https://gist.githubusercontent.com/usutani/10232038/raw/fc7616e65fbddf52e3735016fb86ba79d6e7e06f/osx_oracle_client.md", "size": 172 } }, "public": true, "created_at": "2014-04-09T06:32:46Z", "updated_at": "2014-04-09T06:34:55Z", "description": "OS X Mavericks に Oracle Client をインストール", "comments": 1, "user": { "login": "usutani", "id": 56579, "avatar_url": "https://avatars.githubusercontent.com/u/56579?", "gravatar_id": "c702d3fad57bde7ba189eec1b4c593e3", "url": "https://api.github.com/users/usutani", "html_url": "https://github.com/usutani", "followers_url": "https://api.github.com/users/usutani/followers", "following_url": "https://api.github.com/users/usutani/following{/other_user}", "gists_url": "https://api.github.com/users/usutani/gists{/gist_id}", "starred_url": "https://api.github.com/users/usutani/starred{/owner}{/repo}", "subscriptions_url": "https://api.github.com/users/usutani/subscriptions", "organizations_url": "https://api.github.com/users/usutani/orgs", "repos_url": "https://api.github.com/users/usutani/repos", "events_url": "https://api.github.com/users/usutani/events{/privacy}", "received_events_url": "https://api.github.com/users/usutani/received_events", "type": "User", "site_admin": false }, "comments_url": "https://api.github.com/gists/10232038/comments" },
}
]
```

Comment: The format here is incorrect  as i copy pasted but the format is correct and structure is similar

Comment: Search for GSON (POJO) its quiet neat and efficient. Your response would be mapped into your mapper class directly with GSON.

Comment: Well i am trying something if it works i will let know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try the following

```
String user;
JSONArray data = json.getJSONArray(YOUR_ARRAY); //json is JSONObject
JSONObject object = data.getJSONObject(0);
user = object.getString("user");
```

Comment: user is JsonObject and not a string, plz check.

Comment: @RiteshGune I think json he posted is wrong it should be like {"array":[{ "url": "urlValue", "user": "userValue"}]} so, under this assumption, `array` is `JSONArray` and `JSONObject` has `url` and `user` and I am getting `user`s value from `object` using `getString()` from Object, if my understanding is wrong, please let me know.

Comment: The json op posted is not valid, however if yo check the "user" key; you will see that it is a jsonobject.You can verify that in jsonlint.

Answer (score 1):

As this is a `jsonArray` without a name,

Try following:

1. First get the JsonArray from the result.

   `JSONArray json = new JSONArray(your_json_string);`
2. Then get the single `jsonobject` from `jsonarray` as follows:

   ```
   int arrayLength = json.length();

   for(int i=0;i<arrayLength;i++){   

    // Get the single object in the array
    JSONObject singleObject = json.getJSONObject(i);

    if (singleObject.has("user")) {

       JSONObject userObject = singleObject.getJSONObject("user");
           // TODO: retrieve user jsonobjects data
    }           
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
JSONArray jsonarray = new JSONArray(response);

for (int i=0; i < jsonarray.length(); i++){
    JSONObject jsob = jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);
    String url = jsob.getString("url");
    //same for remaining like url,forks_url etc.,
    JSONObject files_obj = jsob.getJSONObject("files").getJSONObject("gulpfile-viget-pattern.js");
    String type = files_obj.getString("type");
    //same for remaining like type,language etc.,
    JSONObject user_obj = jsob.getJSONObject("user");
    String login = user_obj.getString("login");     
    //same for remaining like login,url etc.,   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your Json Response your first Tag is `JSONArray`. So you need to parse data like,

```
 JSONArray jarray = new JSONArray(Your_Response);

 for (int i=0; i < jarray.length(); i++){
   JSONObject jb= jarray.getJSONObject(i);
   String url = jb.optString("url");

   JSONObject other_jb= jb.getJSONObject("files").getJSONObject("gulpfile-viget-pattern.js");
   String type = other_jb.optString("type");

   JSONObject jsonObject_of_user = jb.getJSONObject("user");
   String user_login = jsonObject_of_user.optString("login");     

 }
```

Comment: I have solved it myself but still selected best answer as anyone in future would get the help